# Talend : tRestClient with @Delete : "HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output"

Tags: web-services, rest, talend

i'm trying to use the @Delete of a Rest WS, so i have :
tXMLMap --> tLog ---> tRestClient --> tLog

The WS path is /api/2/operator/1458  where 1458 is the user id to delete. I don't need any information in the WS body
But i have this error : HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output
Cannot figure out what i'm doing wrong  :/

I've tried to run the job with only
tRestClient --> tLog

With the path hardcoded and this is working, seems that the problem comes from the input. I've tried to remove everything (pass nothing to the RestClient) but i still have the same error

Comment: What are you getting in the tLogRow when you have just a tRestClient and a tLogRow?

Comment: statusCode, body and String. I found a work around by using a subjob and passing the user's id in context, but i think/hope there's a cleaner way to do that